# Equation for $N$-body problem using Jacobi Coordinate

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, coordinate-systems, many-body

For reference on Jacobi Coordinate used for solving 2-Body problem, I referred Wikipedia [Jacobi Coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_coordinates), and on looking at those equation
I can't get the meaning of the symbol **q** in the equation for Vector to center of mass,

**R<sub>jk</sub> = ( m<sub>j</sub>q<sub>j</sub> + m<sub>k</sub>q<sub>k</sub> )( m<sub>j</sub> + m<sub>k</sub> )**

It would be helpful if some one could help.[image: Snippet from Wikipedia]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be an r in the notation that they used before. These are the position vectors of the two objects. And a hint: If you are confused next time, try finding different sources. I'm sure the definition of the center of mass vector can be found elsewhere.

Comment: OK, now that make sense